# Zend form submit does not work after validation fail - only in Chrome

Tags: forms, validation, zend-framework, google-chrome, submit

I have a login form with three inputs - username, password and submit with validation.
If either username or password are empty then validation fails correctly.
However in Chrome I cannot resubmit the form - clicking submit has no effect.
In IE and Firefox it works fine.

```
Zend Controller Action:

public function loginAction()
    {
        $this->_helper->layout->setLayout('layout_nomenu');
        $loginForm = new Application_Form_Login();

        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if ($request->isPost()) {

            if ($loginForm->isValid($request->getPost())) {

                $valid = false;
                if ($valid) {
                //if ($this->_process($loginForm->getValues())) {
                    $this->_helper->redirector('users', 'grid');
                } else {
                    $this->view->loginfail = "Login details not recognised, please try again";
                } 
            } 
        }
        $this->view->login = $loginForm;
    }

forms.ini:

[login]
action = "login"
method = "post"
name = "login"

elements.username.type = "text"
elements.username.options.label = "Username:"
elements.username.options.validators.strlen.validator = "StringLength"
elements.username.options.validators.strlen.options.min = "2"
elements.username.options.validators.strlen.breakChainOnFailure = "true"
elements.username.options.required = "true"

elements.password.type = "password"
elements.password.options.label = "Password:"
elements.password.options.validators.strlen.validator = "StringLength"
elements.password.options.validators.strlen.options.min = "2"
elements.password.options.validators.strlen.breakChainOnFailure = "true"
elements.password.options.required = "true"

elements.submit.type = "submit"
elements.submit.options.label = "Login"

displayGroups.loginform.elements.username   =   "username"
displayGroups.loginform.elements.password   =   "password"
displayGroups.loginform.elements.submit     =   "submit"
displayGroups.loginform.options.legend      =   "Login"

Login form:

class Application_Form_Login extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {

        $config = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/forms.ini', 'login');
        $this->setOptions($config->toArray());
        //$this->addElement('hash', 'no_csrf_foo', array('salt' => 'unique'));

    }
}
```

The html is very simple - no js etc. :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Development </title>



<link href="/css/global.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link href="/css/global.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="/css/development.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>

    <div id="header">

        <div id="header-logo" style="float: left"><img src="/images/small.gif" alt="Development" style="margin-top:5px" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Development</div>

        <div id="header-navigation" style="float: right">

        </div>

    </div>



    <div id="view-content">
<div id="loginform">
<form id="login" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="login" method="post"><dl class="zend_form">

<dt id="loginform-label">&#160;</dt><dd id="loginform-element"><fieldset id="fieldset-loginform"><legend>Login</legend>

<dl>

<dt id="username-label"><label for="username" class="optional">Username:</label></dt>

<dd id="username-element">

<input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="a" />

<ul class="errors"><li>'a' is less than 2 characters long</li></ul></dd>

<dt id="password-label"><label for="password" class="optional">Password:</label></dt>

<dd id="password-element">

<input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" /></dd>

<dt id="submit-label">&#160;</dt><dd id="submit-element">

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login" /></dd></dl></fieldset></dd></dl></form>   <div id="loginerror">
        </div>
</div>
<div id="loginspacer">&nbsp;</div>
</div>


<div id="footer">

<div id="footer-logo"></div>

<div id="footer-navigation">Quetzal Technology 2012</div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ordered a new domain for testing - should be avail tomorrow - will update

Answer (score 0):

maybe try it a little simpler and see what happens:

```
public function loginAction()
    {
        $this->_helper->layout->setLayout('layout_nomenu');
        $loginForm = new Application_Form_Login();

        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if ($request->isPost()) {

            if ($loginForm->isValid($request->getPost())) {

                    $this->_helper->redirector('users', 'grid'); //go here if valid                   
            } else {
            //go here if not valid
            $this->view->loginfail = "Login details not recognised, please try again";

            }          

        } 
        //if  not post show form
        $this->view->login = $loginForm;
    }
```

I have to wonder if that extra loop might be causing a problem in some instances.

Comment: Still seems to be a problem - NB I haven't overridden the isValid form method, I just commented out the  "//if ($this->_process($loginForm->getValues())) {" as this happens after the validation